# Restricting access to hosts file/websites?

Tags: password, firewall, hosts, restricted-access

To keep myself productive, I'd like to block access to certain websites no matter how little willpower I have.

One thing I've done on Windows is password-lock my modified hosts file and kept the password with a friend or somewhere I can't get to it.  But all the "password-protecting" I've seen in Linux is just encryption into a different volume.  My router has a content filter, but stupidly, it doesn't block HTTPS.

Assume I have zero willpower and I'm a heroin addict.  My willpower fails when it comes to keeping applications or Firefox extensions enabled that aren't password-protected.  It's way too easy to just disable them.

I was thinking of just changing my root password so I can't save changes to my hosts file, but sudo will work with my normal login details...  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways that I know of is to go to your Wireless web interface. To do this go to terminal type "ip route"(no "") then look for your gateway IP address. This should be the first thing next to "default via ..."(it should look something like 192.168.1.1). Then type that into your browser IE: Firefox, Google Chrome, etc... as a link or url. You should be prompted for a username and password if so type in anything as your username, and your wifi password (under password). Then look for parental settings, access policy, etc... Under mine it says Restrict internet access on... then add. Click add and look for your IP address/name of your computer. Click yours and under Block Specific Sites put in the URL of youtube.com or other website.  You will probably be asked to put in a parental password so you can use that. Also you probably can't follow these steps to the letter because all Wireless Web Interfaces are different so try other tabs or anything else. If you want to explore more try not to change anything without knowing what it does... it can disable your network or worse.